# In AngularUI Router, do unresolved promise leak?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using angular UI router and I was wondering if anyone knew whether or not unresolved promises when using `resolve` would leak. Our use case is that in certain states, we needed to do some checks and then transition to a different url before the original state loads.

The way we handled this was doing the check and switching the url using `$location` inside `resolve` and leaving an unresolved promise. The unresolved promise was used to prevent the original state's controllers and templates from loading (or else they would've thrown errors).

So my question is, does this practice of leaving unresolved promises cause leakage? I realize an alternative option is to set a long `$timeout` for resolving the promises but if its not necessary, I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to resolve or reject the promise.  I would suggest that the URL switching would take place in the `$stateChangeError` event listener, which would be fired by rejection of the promise.  You can pass the location you want to go to in the `reject([data])` to the listener.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9jxf/2/

Some promise that will reject after a timeout (simulates server call)

```
        protected: ['$timeout', '$q', function ($timeout, $q) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                deferred.reject({type:'redirect',location:'401'});
            }, 1000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
```

This handles the rejection

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (e, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
        if (error.type === 'redirect') {
            $state.transitionTo(error.location);
        }
    });
});
```